# React-intl v5 error when loading a package with react-intl v2

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-intl

I have a React App with `react-intl v2`, and I want to migrate it to `v5`. In our `node_modules` folder we have a dependency with a package that has `react-intl v2`.

I upgraded the React App to use `react-intl v5` and it works fine (The whole App is wrapped with a `IntlProvider`). The problem is when this dependency package is used. I get a:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: [React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object. <IntlProvider> needs to exist in the component ancestry.
    at invariant (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/invariant/browser.js:40:15)
    at invariantIntlContext (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/some-library/dependency-package/node_modules/react-intl/lib/index.es.js:731:52)
    at new InjectIntl(DateTimeFormat) (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/some-library/dependency-packageg/node_modules/react-intl/lib/index.es.js:813:7)
```

I am importing the package as usual with `import`. I am using `webpack` for bundling. Since it's an external package, it should be compile before rendering, that means, it does not matter that the dependency package is in a lower version right? I should just get the HTML and my React App just renders it.

Answer (score 0):

In webpack you should force resolution of react-intl to v5